# PHP Upload Form, "Notice: Undefined index: upload"

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I searched around google and stackoverflow, but didnt quite find the right answer.

im using a form. Within this form i have a simple uploader

```
<form method="post" action="uploadImage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="upload" id="upload" type="file" />
   <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="add">
</form>
```

Now, in my uploadImage.php file, i have written, below

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES['upload']);
print "</pre>";
```

when i upload a image with filesize about below 1.5MB, an array with info of that file is returned.
But when i upload a file with about 2MB size, i get 1 error, and no filesize.
when i upload a 8MB file i get this error,
Notice:  Undefined index: upload in C:\Program Files........\uploadImage.php on line 2

I think the problem has something to do with upload limitations, the question is how can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a .htaccess file in your root folder and put the following code in it.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: how can i rename a txt file to become .htaccess

Comment: if you are using windows then open a notepad > save as > choose all file types and give the filename as .htaccess

Comment: If you are using windows you may not be using apache and an .htaccess file won't work

Comment: can you check your maximum upload filesize limit with this code. <?php echo $max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')); ?>

Comment: well, i do have a apache and mysql server running

Comment: @adam he said he is using easyphp which means it is another version of WAMP.

Comment: by the way, what does these two commands mean?

php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200

Comment: php_value max_execution_time Limits the maximum execution time, max_input_time determines how much time PHP will wait to receive file data

Comment: have a look at this article this may help solve your problem  http://blog.jc21.com/2007-05-03/change-the-maximum-upload-size-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

That first error is because you hit [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/upload_max_filesize) limit, and that another notice comes when you hit [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/post_max_size).

`post_max_size` generally should be set to a higher value than `upload_max_filesize` since there is some extra overhead/bytes involved.

Comment: oki, i think i got it now. Found out where php.ini is on my simulated server.

Comment: nice, it works now everyone. Tnx for explaning this to me in detail.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini has directives that control max upload size, specifically post_max_size and upload_max_filesize, the latter of which defaults to 2M. [Look here.](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: where can i find the php.ini when im running the page through eayphp?

Comment: i would not recommend directly editing the php.ini file because most of the host won't allow you to do it. it is always better to use .htaccess instead.

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini you need to edit the line upload_max_filesize to a higher value.  2MB is the default limit.